# Model, lexicon to do fine grained emotions analysis on text in r

Tags: r, nlp, r-package, emotion

I want to analyse a text, looking for emotions (not only anger, trust,...) but also finer with terms like (vigilance, hate, boredom,...) .

Kind regards and thx,
Rob

Does someone know a package, model, lexicon to do this, in the r language?

Comment: I'm not sure whether they cover this level of detail, but have a look at the `qdap` and `sentimentr` packages.